# Jogando Info do Controller para View CI3

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc, view

estou trabalhando com CodeIgniter3 no modelo MVC e estou tendo problemas faz tempo, aos poucos vou resolvendo alguns problemas aqui e ali e to quase chegando no ponto.

Estou fazendo uma consulta por ordem aleatória no DB pelo model:

```
public function get_rand(){

$frase = $this->db->query("SELECT frase FROM frases ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
if($frase->num_rows() > 0):
    return $frase->result();
else:
    return NULL;
endif;
```

}

e puxando dentro do Controller:

```
public function index(){
    if($frase = $this->randfrase->get_rand(1)):
            foreach ($frase as $linha) :
                    echo $linha->frase;
            endforeach;
    else:
            return NULL;
    endif;
```

}

montei ele assim para poder ver por URL se estava funcionando a seleção Randomica. A parte do Model esta 100%, agora queria saber como posso ao invés de printa, mandar a info para uma view aside do meu sistema.
alguem poderia dar uma ajuda.
No caso essa informação deveria aparecer em um aside que é padrão para todo o site.
Eu tentei colocar esse codigo do controller direto na view mas ele sempre da erro:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$randfrase
>
> Filename: views/aside.php
>
> Line Number: 3
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\site\application\views\aside.php
>   Line: 3 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\site\application\views\home.php
>   Line: 27 Function: view
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\site\application\controllers\pagina.php
>   Line: 14 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\site\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_rand() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\site\application\views\aside.php on line 3
>   A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function get_rand() on a non-object
>
> Filename: views/aside.php
>
> Line Number: 3
>
> Backtrace:

Answer (score 0):

Nunca usei o tal do `aside`, mas parece ser uma view normal no final das contas..

bem.. o que eu **acho** que entendi foi que vc não está chamando a model corretamente, então ve se te ajuda em alguma coisa

Vamos supor que sua model se chama **Randfrase** e sua aside se chame **aside** somente.

então ao meu ver, tem de ficar assim no seu controller:

public function index(){

```
if($frase = $this->randfrase->get_rand(1)){
    //carrega a model
    $this->load->model('randfrase'); 

    //utiliza o método da model
    $dados['frase'] = $this->randfrase->get_rand(); 

    //sua aside seria uma view no meu exemplo que recebe o array
    $this->load->view('aside',$dados);
}
```

}

Agora na sua view **aside** você faz mais ou menos o que tentou fazer antes assim:

```
foreach ($frase as $linha) :
    echo $linha->frase;
endforeach;
```

Espero que seja mais ou menos isso o que você precisa.. boa sorte.